# How do I sync scrolling in two treeviews using the slider

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (C#) and a Windows Forms application.

I have two treeviews side by side, and I have figured out how to synchronise the scrolling using the up/down buttons on the scrollbar, but when I use the slider it does not move the other treeview. I have taken a listview example that works, but the same code does not work for treeviews.

So far I have, in the main form:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);

    private void myListBox1_Scroll(ref Message m)
    {
        SendMessage(myListBox2.Handle, (uint)m.Msg, (uint)m.WParam, (uint)m.LParam);
    }
```

I have created a control:

```
public partial class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event ScrollEventHandler Scroll;
    public delegate void ScrollEventHandler(ref Message m);


    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
            if (Scroll != null)
            {
                Scroll(ref m);
            }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
```

which I add two of to the form.

I can use the same code to have a listivew control the treeview and that will work if you drag the slider, but in reverse it only works with the up down buttons.

Comment: Anyone using Win32 from .Net will find http://www.pinvoke.net/ very useful.  It's a great resource and I've found it invaluable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than use SendMessage and mark your DLL as unsafe you can use the `GetScrollPos` and `SetScrollPos` functions from user32.dll.

I've wrapped the code up into your MyTreeView class so it's nicely encapsulated.

You just need to call the `AddLinkedTreeView` method like so:

```
treeView1.AddLinkedTreeView(treeView2);
```

Here's the source for the MyTreeView class.

```
public partial class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    public MyTreeView() : base()
    {
    }

    private List<MyTreeView> linkedTreeViews = new List<MyTreeView>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Links the specified tree view to this tree view.  Whenever either treeview
    /// scrolls, the other will scroll too.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="treeView">The TreeView to link.</param>
    public void AddLinkedTreeView(MyTreeView treeView)
    {
        if (treeView == this)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot link a TreeView to itself!", "treeView");

        if (!linkedTreeViews.Contains(treeView))
        {
            //add the treeview to our list of linked treeviews
            linkedTreeViews.Add(treeView);
            //add this to the treeview's list of linked treeviews
            treeView.AddLinkedTreeView(this);

            //make sure the TreeView is linked to all of the other TreeViews that this TreeView is linked to
            for (int i = 0; i < linkedTreeViews.Count; i++)
            {
                //get the linked treeview
                var linkedTreeView = linkedTreeViews[i];
                //link the treeviews together
                if (linkedTreeView != treeView)
                    linkedTreeView.AddLinkedTreeView(treeView);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the destination's scroll positions to that of the source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source of the scroll positions.</param>
    /// <param name="dest">The destinations to set the scroll positions for.</param>
    private void SetScrollPositions(MyTreeView source, MyTreeView dest)
    {
        //get the scroll positions of the source
        int horizontal = User32.GetScrollPos(source.Handle, Orientation.Horizontal);
        int vertical = User32.GetScrollPos(source.Handle, Orientation.Vertical);
        //set the scroll positions of the destination
        User32.SetScrollPos(dest.Handle, Orientation.Horizontal, horizontal, true);
        User32.SetScrollPos(dest.Handle, Orientation.Vertical, vertical, true);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        //process the message
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        //pass scroll messages onto any linked views
        if (m.Msg == User32.WM_VSCROLL || m.Msg == User32.WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            foreach (var linkedTreeView in linkedTreeViews)
            {
                //set the scroll positions of the linked tree view
                SetScrollPositions(this, linkedTreeView);
                //copy the windows message
                Message copy = new Message
                {
                    HWnd = linkedTreeView.Handle,
                    LParam = m.LParam,
                    Msg = m.Msg,
                    Result = m.Result,
                    WParam = m.WParam
                };
                //pass the message onto the linked tree view
                linkedTreeView.RecieveWndProc(ref copy);
            }                               
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recieves a WndProc message without passing it onto any linked treeviews.  This is useful to avoid infinite loops.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="m">The windows message.</param>
    private void RecieveWndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Imported functions from the User32.dll
    /// </summary>
    private class User32
    {
        public const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
        public const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;  

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Orientation nBar);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Orientation nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Added forwarding of the WM_MOUSEWHEEL message as per MinnesotaFat's suggestion.

Comment: When do I call 'treeView1.AddLinkedTreeView(treeView2);' exactly? I have .net 2.0 and there is no Scroll-Event for Treeviews...

Answer (score 2):

I have done this with `TextBoxes` before, but I think the solution should work for you as well:

```
// Get/Set Scroll positions of a control handle
private unsafe Win32.POINT GetScrollPos(System.IntPtr myHandle)
{
   Win32.POINT res = new Win32.POINT();
   IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(&res);
   Win32.SendMessage(myHandle, Win32.EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ptr);
   return res;
}

private unsafe void SetScrollPos(Win32.POINT point, System.IntPtr myHandle)
{
   IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(&point);
   Win32.SendMessage(myHandle, Win32.EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, ptr);
}
```

Win32 details

```
public const int WM_USER = 0x400;
public const int EM_GETSCROLLPOS  = (WM_USER + 221);
public const int EM_SETSCROLLPOS  = (WM_USER + 222);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT 
{
   public int x;
   public int y;
}

[DllImport("user32")] public static extern int SendMessage(
    HWND hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Then just attached to both of the `ListView` scrolled events and do something like this:

```
private void ListView1Scrolled(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   SetScrollPos(GetScrollPos(ListView1.Handle), ListView2.Handle);
}

private void ListView2Scrolled(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   SetScrollPos(GetScrollPos(ListView2.Handle), ListView1.Handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DoctaJonez' answer works marvellously. For completeness, if you add another condition to the `if` statement in the `WndProc` method, you can handle the mouse wheel scrolling events as well:

```
if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
```

And declare WM_MOUSEWHEEL:

```
private cont int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
```