# Hiding TableLayoutPanel Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar, tablelayoutpanel

I have two adjacent TableLaoutPanels, which are syncronized together as explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6456738/1543816

I need to hide the vertical scrollbar of one of them.

I tried setting AutoScroll to false but this disables scrolling altogether.
Can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using SourceGride is a much better way:

https://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/

Comment: this is at least not an answer, at worst spam. please resolve that